# Invalid method with MPGS payment gateway

Tags: checkout, error, payment-methods

I am trying to implement our **new MPGS payment gateway** but have run into a problem on the **live server** that did not appear on the test server. All ran smoothly on the localhost.

When posting a call to api/rest/createsession/ I receive a 500 Internal Server Error.

The response is:

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":0,"message":"Invalid method Mastercard_Mpgs_Model_MpgsApi_Rest::_critical
(Array\n(\n    [0] => Resource internal error.\n)\n)"}]}}
```

Exception log stack trace:

```
2017-02-03T02:58:06+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mastercard_Mpgs_Model_MpgsApi_Rest::_critical(Array
(
[0] => Resource internal error.
)
)' in /home/safetyli/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php:653
Stack trace:
#0     /home/safetyli/public_html/app/code/community/Mastercard/Mpgs/Model/MpgsApi/Rest.php(84): Varien_Object->__call('_critical', Array)
#1 /home/safetyli/public_html/app/code/community/Mastercard/Mpgs/Model/MpgsApi/Rest.php(84): Mastercard_Mpgs_Model_MpgsApi_Rest->_critical('Resource intern...')
#2 /home/safetyli/public_html/app/code/community/Mastercard/Mpgs/Model/MpgsApi/Rest.php(113): Mastercard_Mpgs_Model_MpgsApi_Rest->sender(1, 'session', Array)
#3 /home/safetyli/public_html/app/code/community/Mastercard/Mpgs/Model/Api2/Restapi/Rest/Guest/V1.php(63): Mastercard_Mpgs_Model_MpgsApi_Rest->create_checkout_session('100001721-5893f...', Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#4 /home/safetyli/public_html/app/code/community/Mastercard/Mpgs/Model/Api2/Restapi/Rest/Guest/V1.php(106): Mastercard_Mpgs_Model_Api2_Restapi_Rest_Guest_V1->_create(Array)
#5 /home/safetyli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Dispatcher.php(74): Mastercard_Mpgs_Model_Api2_Restapi_Rest_Guest_V1->dispatch()
#6 /home/safetyli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(239): Mage_Api2_Model_Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request), Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Response))
#7 /home/safetyli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(107): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->_dispatch(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request), Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Response), Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_User_Guest))
#8 /home/safetyli/public_html/api.php(73): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->run()
#9 {main}
```

Ive looked at Mastercard/Mpgs/Model/MpgsApi/Rest.php but not sure what to change.

Does anyone have any idea of where to start troubleshooting? I've tried a few things without much success. I am not a coder so go easy on me.

Cheers

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. proxy CURLOPT_PROXY and
2. CURLOPT_PROXYPORT

Try to add above 2 variables values in you CURL request.

That solved my problem.